# Error when checking input: expected dense_8_input to have 2 dimensions

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, mnist

I am trying to run a simple network for classifying MNIST:

```
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

When I try to fit:

```
network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs =5, batch_size = 128)
```

I get this error:

> Error when checking input: expected dense_8_input to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)

What am I doing worng?

Comment: input_shape = (28,28,) not (28*28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model expects each input sample to have a shape of `(784,)` (i.e. `input_shape=(28 * 28,)`). However, as the error shows, the input array currently has a shape of `(num_samples, 28, 28)`. So you need to reshape it:

```
import numpy as np

train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (-1, 28*28))
```